# yahoo finance stock data / class PagesController < ApplicationController MET_AKEY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yahoo-finance

I am sorry if my question is not specific enough, however, I hope somebody will answer. I want to display stock market data with rails.

I have the following code as an example:

class PagesController < ApplicationController

def index

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
@capabilities = Capability.all

url = "http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/val/wxfcs/all/xml/sitelist?key=#{MET_AKEY}"

@docxml = Nokogiri::XML(open(url))
```

end

def show

```
@capability = Capability.find(params[:id])
gon.latitude = @capability.latitude
gon.longitude = @capability.longtitude
```

end

end

Now I want to change the url. My purpose is to get access to the yahoo finance stock data.

1) Which url I have to use? (I really tried to find it)

2) I guess I have to change my the gem file. Which other files I have to change in my application?

Answer (score 0):

You should use their API instead of scraping page, check [that link](http://www.transparentech.com/projects/yahoofinance) and try using it, if you will have aby trouble post specific error.